# Delete everything but the first n items (Rails, PGSQL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

Assume I have a table called post, that belongs to user.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < activeRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

Such that the `posts` table contains a `user_id` column.

How can I periodically, delete all but the first n posts from the `posts` table for each user?

Assume `n = 20`

If a user has 15 posts, then all 15 are kept.

If a user has 21 posts, then 1 post is deleted. The 1 being the oldest one.

Basically I need to do a FIFO but with grouping to the `user_id` column.

How can this be achieved via raw PostgreSQL sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rank the post using `ROW_NUMBER()` in a common table expression, ranking the newest per user_id as 1 (and increasing for older posts). Then just use a simple delete to delete all rows where the rank is greater than 20;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY id DESC) rn
  FROM post
)
DELETE FROM post
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM cte WHERE rn>20);
```

[A simple SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ada56/1).

And as always, back up your data before running potentially destructive SQL from random people on the Internet.